# Can't use wget to download https letsencrypt sites on server, but on Mac it works. Doesn't work for Facebook scraper

Tags: apache, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have https via LetsEncrypt installed on my domain https://blog.andytriboletti.com
No errors in the browser on Mac or on iPhone.
I noticed a problem where Facebook's open graph URL scraper used for previews wasn't working.

After investigating I noticed that wget https://blog.andytriboletti.com works on my Macbook, but does not work on my Centos server.  On Mac I am using wget version GNU Wget 1.17.1 built on darwin15.2.0. On Centos I am using GNU Wget 1.14 built on linux-gnu.  I upgraded to GNU Wget 1.18 built on linux-gnu and it still doesn't work.

How Debugger sees your URL is blank:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.andytriboletti.com%2F

I have opened a bug with Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/546742535513914/

I have tried posting site with Google Plus and the preview works: https://plus.google.com/+AndyTriboletti/posts/3uzLN83Ysgn

Full output of wget --version and it working to download https://blog.andytriboletti.com/ on my Macbook:

```
Andys-MBP:~ andytriboletti$ brew upgrade wget
Error: wget 1.17.1 already installed
Andys-MBP:~ andytriboletti$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.17.1 built on darwin15.2.0.

+digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 -iri +large-file -metalink -nls +ntlm 
+opie -psl +ssl/openssl 

Wgetrc: 
    /usr/local/etc/wgetrc (system)
Compile: 
    clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/usr/local/etc/wgetrc" 
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.17.1/share/locale" -I. 
    -I../lib -I../lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -DNDEBUG 
Link: 
    clang -DNDEBUG -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz 
    ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a 

Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Please send bug reports and questions to <bug-wget@gnu.org>.
Andys-MBP:~ andytriboletti$ wget https://blog.andytriboletti.com/
--2016-06-20 15:44:41--  https://blog.andytriboletti.com/
Resolving blog.andytriboletti.com... 104.237.138.56, 2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe84:6879
Connecting to blog.andytriboletti.com|104.237.138.56|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html.16'

index.html.16                         [ <=>                                                       ]  55.68K  --.-KB/s    in 0.09s   

2016-06-20 15:44:41 (641 KB/s) - 'index.html.16' saved [57012]
```

When I run this on my Linux server I do get an error:

```
-bash-4.2$ wget https://blog.andytriboletti.com/
--2016-06-19 13:10:44--  https://blog.andytriboletti.com/
Resolving blog.andytriboletti.com (blog.andytriboletti.com)... 2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe84:6879, 104.237.138.56
Connecting to blog.andytriboletti.com (blog.andytriboletti.com)|2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe84:6879|:443... connected.
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
    requested host name ‘blog.andytriboletti.com’.
To connect to blog.andytriboletti.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

As well as wget, it's also an issue with curl.

Facebook URL previews work with a domain I bought using a Namecheap cert.

Answer (score 0):

Posted on letsencrypt forums and it's an issue with having an IPv6 dns record for this domain but Apache not setup for IPv6 on this domain.

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/cant-use-wget-to-download-https-letsencrypt-sites-on-server-but-on-mac-it-works-doesnt-work-for-facebook-scraper/17237/2